# Grammar : Adverb Or Adjective (noticeably or noticeable)

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> Jack steadily progressed, **noticeably** through increased eye contact and a louder voice.

In this sentence, which one is grammatically right, 'noticeable' or 'noticeably'?

Here, I'd like to express that I noticed his progress and change from our increased eye contact and his louder voice when he gave a speech in English. He is an English language learner who is at beginner level. And I am his English tutor.

Comment: If you want to say that he "progressed through increased eye contact..", then **noticeably** is your choice.

Comment: Here, I'd like to express that I noticed his progress and change from our increased eye contact and his louder voice when he gave a speech in English. He is an English language learner who is at beginner level. And I am his English tutor.

Answer (score 2):

> Jack steadily progressed, **noticeably** through increased eye contact and a louder voice.

In this example, *noticeably* modifies his progress (progressed). So you would use an adverb (noticeably) to modify a verb.
To use the adjective form you would have it modify a noun:

> Jack steadily progressed, through ***noticeable*** eye contact and a louder voice.

Comment: +1 I guess we can also write "Jack steadily progressed, **noticeable** through increased eye contact and a louder voice." -- but that would mean that "Jack, a noticeable person thanks to increased eye contact and a louder voice, steadily progressed." The meaning will change.

Comment: So with the word 'noticeable', it wouldn't be the same meaning as what I stated before, i.e., his progress is noticeable as I can tell from our increased eye contact. Do I understand correctly? So, in conclusion, it should be the word 'noticeably', right?

Comment: You said "I noticed his progress" which relates *notice* to *progress*. But "his progress *is* noticeable" is different, because intransitive verb *to be* makes *notice* relate to *his (Jack)*.